# Can I use word-context-count pairs as input to gensim's Word2Vec

Tags: word2vec, gensim

I want to train word2vec (using gensim) on a large corpus data. The information I have is only co-occurence of any two words. My data has the format of
word__tab__context_word__tab__Number
(e.g: danger of 10, meaning '*danger*' and '*of*' co-occured 10 times in a window size of 5 in the corpus) for each line. 
Does word2vec of gensim take such input? I have searched through gensim tutorials and havn't seen any examples like this.

Thanks a lot for help. 
Li

Comment: What have you tried so far? please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Gensim doesn't take that as input; it expects actual text examples.

But, you could approximate skip-gram training by generating a synthetic corpus from your information.

For `danger of 10`, just generate 10 texts, each of `['danger', 'of']`. (Gensim `Word2Vec` expects token-lists.) These synthetic texts will result in `Word2Vec` training encountering 10 skip-gram training-examples of 'danger' predicting 'of', and 10 skip-gram training-examples of 'of' predicting 'danger'. (So, if your co-occurrence lists also include `of danger 10`, you may want to discard those to avoid double-synthesis.)

It won't exactly be true skip-gram with a `window` of 5, because training on real texts randomly shrinks the window, to give closer words more weight – and your data doesn't include information on closeness. But it should be similar in results if you have no other options.